# Mir wird "das alles" zu viel

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar-identification, demonstrative-pronoun

I know this sentence mean:

> Everything is too much for me.

But my question is about the "das alles". It doesn't make sense since it means "the everything". Please explain me what's the reason for that.

Comment: Actually a better translation of *das alles* would be *all that* and it can also be rearranged in German to *All das* as presented by @infinitezero.

Answer (score 6):

Here *das* is not an article but a demonstrative pronoun ([Demonstrativpronomen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonstrativpronomen)). So the proper literal translation is

> this/that all is getting too much for me

You can rephrase it, so it becomes more apparent

> All das/dies wird mir zu viel

Comment: The "alles" doesn't make sense here. It doesn't have the translation of "everything" here. Does it mean "entirely"?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between everything and all?

Comment: Ok let me rephrase the original German sentence. Das wird mir "alles” zu viel. What is "alles" doing here?

Comment: It has the same meaning as before.